# Array and foreach

Tags: php, arrays

```
$posts = array(
"message" => 'this is a test message'
);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
     echo $post['message'];
}
```

Why does the above code only output the first letter in message? "t".

Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually surprised it prints anything at all... You shouldn't be able to index into a string using an associative parameter (ie. a string)... I'd say this probably undefined behaviour at best.

Comment: @Matthew: The explanation for that is in my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

foreach takes each element of the array and assigns it to the variable.  To get the results I assume you are expecting you just need to do:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
   echo $post;
}
```

The specifics as to why your code didn't work: `$post` would be the contents of the array element - in this case a string.  Because PHP isn't strongly typed / supports type juggling, you can in fact work with a string as if it were an array, and get to each character in the sequence:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post[0]; //'t'
    echo $post[1]; //'h'
}
```

Obviously `$post['message']` therefore is not a valid element, and there is no explicit conversion from `(string)'message'` to `int`, so this evals to `$post[0]`.

Comment: ((int) 'message') is pretty well defined: http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: Very true: bad choice of vocabulary on my part to express what I meant

Answer (score 6):

```
# $posts is an array with one index ('message')
$posts = array(
    "message" => 'this is a test message'
);

# You iterate over the $posts array, so $post contains
# the string 'this is a test message'
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    # You try to access an index in the string.
    # Background info #1:
    #   You can access each character in a string using brackets, just
    #   like with arrays, so $post[0] === 't', $post[1] === 'e', etc.
    # Background info #2:
    #   You need a numeric index when accessing the characters of a string.
    # Background info #3:
    #   If PHP expects an integer, but finds a string, it tries to convert
    #   it. Unfortunately, string conversion in PHP is very strange.
    #   A string that does not start with a number is converted to 0, i.e.
    #   ((int) '23 monkeys') === 23, ((int) 'asd') === 0,
    #   ((int) 'strike force 1') === 0
    # This means, you are accessing the character at position ((int) 'message'),
    # which is the first character in the string
    echo $post['message'];
}
```

What you possibly want is either this:

```
$posts = array(
    array(
        "message" => 'this is a test message'
    )
);
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post['message'];
}
```

Or this:

```
$posts = array(
    "message" => 'this is a test message'
);
foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
    # $key === 'message'
    echo $post;
}
```

Comment: That's not really solving the problem, which is an obvious mis-conception about how foreach works with arrays.

Comment: 'Solving the problem'? Of course I can't solve the problem without knowing what he wants to achieve with his script, I can only answer his question and give working examples. But I do think the info here is enough to make his script work.

Answer (score 4):

I'd add to iAn's answer something: if you want somehow to access to the key of the value, use this:

```
foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
    echo $key . '=' . $post;
}
```

Result:

```
message=this is a test message
```